# Images not being copied into dist folder

Tags: configuration, webpack-5

I am new with webpack and using 5.0, following is my scripted but images aren't being copied to`dist/`folder I followed basic config still it doesn't generate images. What am I doing wrong?

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    mode : "development",
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        assetModuleFilename: '[name][ext]'
    },
    devtool : 'eval-cheap-source-map',
    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
          },
    },
   loader: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
            type: 'assets/resource'
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loeader']
        }
    ]
   }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in the second rule, `use` array where you write css-loeader instead of css-loader.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely none of your source files reference the images that you are missing. Webpack attempts to omit any files that are not referenced by / traced back to your entry points. Here are some ways how to tell webpack that you are using certain images:

### Use import in JS file

If you load images directly from JavaScript you would have to add an `import` statement line like the following to your JS file:

```js
import MyImageFile from "./images/my-image-file.svg";

// how to use later (here with jQuery):
$(document).append('<img src="' + MyImageFile + '" />').
```

assuming that you organized you image files to actually be in the directory `images` relative to the JS file using them.

### CSS files

You can also reference images files from CSS files and webpack will recognize that:

```css
.myclass {
    background: url('./images/another-image.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Again, assuming this image is in sub-directory `images` relative to the CSS file referencing it.

### Use Webpack's CopyWebpackPlugin

A third way is to *manually* copy images files using the `CopyWebpackPlugin` in the webpack config file like so:

```js
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    // ...you webpack config...
    plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
            { from: "src/images/my-icon-file.ico", to: "images/my-icon-file.ico" },
        ],
    }),
}
```

In this case you need to hard-code you image file path and file name in your source code.

See here for usage https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/#root